# Profile rest service in JProfiler

Tags: java, rest, jprofiler

I have a rest service which is called by a client and the rest service in turn calls a second rest service. All the services and the client are running on the same JVM. I wanted to measure the time taken in various methods/threads which get invoked in this flow including the time they are sleeping as some methods in the first rest service sleep and then poll the second rest service after waking up(in a separate thread), to get the status of the current task. I was not able to find a way to trace a rest api call in JProfiler. Any pointers?

Comment: You mean like the "Request tracking" feature, only for REST calls? This would be difficult to implement for cross-VM calls in general because there are no hooks that could be used to insert a globally unique request ID. Does the HTTP splitting feature of the servlet probe help you solve your use case?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I ended up using open tracing as that may be the better suited option for me